# My boss hasn't called me in to work in a week even though he said he would, what should I do?

Tags: communication, new-job, manager, new-hires, first-job

I recently got a job at a coffee shop.

I've worked 5 shifts in two weeks and my boss seemed to like me. He said my first paycheck would come in next week (this week) last Wednesday which was my last shift.

I told him I couldn't work that weekend because I was going to be out of the country for Christmas and he said it was absolutely fine. I told him I'd be back Wednesday (two days ago) and he said he would text me about my next shift Wednesday. It's now almost Saturday and I haven't heard from him since last Wednesday.

What should I do? Text him? What should I say? What if I am fired?

Answer (score 12):

Call him. Even if they don't want to use you any more, they owe you a paycheck.  Communication is key - we can't read his mind. Don't text him unless he's a teenager.

Comment: And when he's a teenager, still dont text.

Comment: Well, this is all confusing advice because her boss specifically said "he would text" her.  So texting is going to happen, probably at some point.  Unless you're insinuating she shouldn't initiate a text, which I'm not sure if that's even a cultural snafu.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to assume anything's wrong at this point - your boss could just be busy getting back from the holiday period. Call your boss (or even drop by the coffee shop), say you're back, and ask when your next shift is. Chances are, everything will be fine.

It is *possible* that you're being let go by them not bothering to contact you, but the legality of this would vary depending on the country you're in. I wouldn't assume this was the first option, though.